# Jquery basic: How to randomize this array and still call all the parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 divs, `#col1` and `#col2`, that I need to generate some divs with fruit names in there.

So far I have:

```
var fruitArray = ['apples','banana','orange','grapes'];
for (fruit in fruitArray) {
    $('<div class="'+fruitArray[fruit]+'"></div>').appendTo('#col1').doSomething(); 

    $('<div id="'+fruitArray[fruit]+'"></div>').appendTo('#col2').doSomething(); 
}
```

Which turns out like:

```
<div id="#col1">
    <div class="apples"></div>
    <div class="banana"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="grapes"></div>
</div>
<div id="#col2">
    <div id="apples"></div>
    <div id="banana"></div>
    <div id="orange"></div>
    <div id="grapes"></div>
</div>
```

How do I randomize the array so it looks something like:

```
<div id="#col1">
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="apples"></div>
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="grapes"></div>
</div>
<div id="#col2">
    <div id="grapes"></div>
    <div id="orange"></div>
    <div id="apples"></div>
    <div id="banana"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have 2 orange divs at firstColumn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `shuffle` extension:

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
    var shuffledArray = [];
    while (this.length) {
        shuffledArray.push(this.splice(Math.random() * this.length, 1)[0]);
    }
    while (shuffledArray.length) {
        this.push(shuffledArray.pop());
    }
    return this;
}
```

Use it like

```
var fruitArray = ['apples','banana','orange','grapes'].shuffle();
for (var i = 0; i < fruitArray.length; i++) {            
    $('<div class="'+fruitArray[i]+'"></div>').appendTo('#col1').doSomething(); 

    $('<div id="'+fruitArray[i]+'"></div>').appendTo('#col2').doSomething(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is great, except I seem to be seeing the shuffle function after my divs? Any idea why?

Comment: @user1193783: Because `for(fruit in fruitArray)` iterates over the **properties** of the object, not only the array elements. And since you extended `Array.prototype`, `shuffle` is now a property of all arrays. That's why you should (a) never use `for...in` to iterate over an array and (b) avoid to extend prototypes of built-in objects.

Comment: @FelixKling Of course you're right. I've edited my example to use a `for`-loop.

Comment: Thank you! It's now running smoother too.